# Python: Insertion sort algorithm

Tags: python-3.4

I am currently working through the Insertion Sort Algorithm for my A-Levels and my teacher would like me to randomly generate numbers for a list however instead of starting with the minimum values she wants me to start with the maximum values and work down to minimum values. I have searched and couldn't find a way of doing this. Was hoping someone here could help.

```
import random 
array = [] 
elements = int(input("Insert how many elements you want: ")) 
for i in range(0, elements): 
    array.append(random.randint(1,1000000)) 
print("Original list:",array,)
```

Comment: What do you mean starting with maximum? It's random, isn't that the point? Are you looking for the [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) library? It's unclear what your asking - provide example, and preferably an initial attempt by you.

Comment: This is part of the code i have. It asks the user for an input and randomly creates numbers dependant on how many i need. My teacher wants me to change it so the random numbers desend in order from largest to smallest without needing to have a defined list.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Isnt the point to sort the list after you create it with that?

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: That is the point, however she wants it re-written to create the most amount of comparisons and swaps, which is why i need to have it largest to smallest

Comment: So you want the list to be random numbers yet sorted largest to smallest only to sort them to smallest to largest?  Why not just make the list not random and count down from max to min in the list, it would give you the highest number of comparisons right?

Comment: That is pretty much what she wants yes. However we also have to time how long it takes the program to do this. The code has to include random numbers as criteria and also has to be as compact as possible, otherwise i would randomly generate the numbers, order them, then reverse them to time how long it would take

Comment: Okay so your options are to sort the list or make the list from N to 0 and then sort it into whatever order you would like.  However we cannot write the code out for you.

Comment: that is fine, I can write it myself thanks for the advice